# How to send table colums result of database from server to client and put it into multiple listview?

Tags: android, database, listview

So I have database myphp on localhost server contains this Table
TABLE NAME : SONGS,
COLUMNS : TRACK_NUMBER, SINGER, ALBUM, YEAR. What i want to do is that
select all the values from those colums then send it to client and put all the values into multiple list(i want to make the listview like on picture). What method should i use, to send query result into client so I can use it for multiple listview?

Could you tell me tutorials or reference to do these stuffs? I know its so much to ask, but I really need your help, I am totally newbie to android so hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to parse data from webserver to your android application.

i.e.: `JSON parsing, XML parsing`

For your scenario,I recommend to use JSON as it is lightweight and easy to use.

**Reference:**

[parsing data from php's mysql database to android](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2011/09/connecting-mysql-database-in-android.html)

[json-parsing-tutorial](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/)

If you want to learn everything in depth, there is a good series of tutorial with images,video and code snippets, have a look at [Android, MySQL, PHP, & JSON | Remote Databases Tutorial](http://www.mybringback.com/tutorial-series/12924/)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Thank you so much, thank you so much. ill read the tutorials. once again thank you so much. :D

Comment: @josepnabu: I'm glad to help you.and yes, It would be nice if you can express your gratitude `once more` by upvoting or accepting my answer. `:-)`

Comment: so i  downloaded and tested it, but i got eror when tried to parse the string into JSON Object in JSonParser class. how do i fix that?

Comment: thank you, but i have fixed it. i have accepted your answer. Thanks again by the way :)